# How to sum all rows from a column into two joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, group-by

```
SELECT movies.name, 
       general.[date], 
       Sum(general.price) AS GeneralPrice
FROM movies 
     INNER JOIN general ON movies.IDmovie=general.IDmovie
GROUP BY movie.name, general.[date]
HAVING SUM(((general.[date])=#8/11/2014#));
```

So this is my query.

Here is my tables.

```
TABLE 1 - MOVIES:

IDmovie | Name 
--------+------------
1       | Something1
2       | Something2
3       | Something3
4       | Something4


TABLE 2 - GENERAL

IDmovie | Date     | Price 
--------+----------+---------
1       | 11.08.14 | $10 
2       | 14.08.14 | $12 
3       | 12.08.14 | $18,60 
4       | 11.08.14 | $20 
5       | 19.08.14 | $13
```

So how u see with my query i get the names of the movies and the prices to all movies with date 8.11.14 and put em into third table. And my question is how to SUM all the prices like :

```
| Date     | Price  | General Price 
+----------+--------+--------------
| 11.08.14 | $10    | $40,60 
| 11.08.14 | $12    |
| 11.08.14 | $18,60 |
```

What i should add into the query ?

Comment: Does this have something to do with SQL-server?

Comment: You can't really sum dates. Don't you want WHERE general.[date]=#8/11/2014# instead?

Comment: i do a sql query into access

Comment: i dont want to sum dates i want to sum the prices but in sql view in access

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @movies TABLE
  (
     IDmovie INT,
     Name    VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO @movies
VALUES      (1,
             'Something1'),
            (2,
             'Something2'),
            (3,
             'Something3'),
            (4,
             'Something4')

DECLARE @GENERAL TABLE
  (
     IDmovie INT,
     [Date]  DATE,
     Price   FLOAT
  )

INSERT INTO @GENERAL
VALUES      (1,
             '11/aug/14',
             10),
            (2,
             '14/aug/14',
             12),
            (3,
             '11/aug/14',
             18.60),
            (4,
             '11/aug/14',
             20),
            (5,
             '19/aug/14',
             13)

SELECT *
FROM   @movies

SELECT *
FROM   @GENERAL

SELECT g.[date],
       g.Price,
       (SELECT sum(g1.Price)
        FROM   @GENERAL g1
        WHERE  g1.Date = g.Date) AS general_price
FROM   @movies m
       INNER JOIN @GENERAL g
               ON m.IDmovie = g.IDmovie
GROUP  BY g.[date],
          g.Price
HAVING g.[date] = '8/11/2014'
```